# Java development on files located on remote machine

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been developing in Java using VIM or Notepad++ editors and my java code is on remote linux machine. For small changes, I just putty/vnc to the remote linux machine; for big changes, I use Notepad++ as it has FTP integrated into it. In Notepad ++, I browse the remote files, download the files I want to edit, and just saving the file saves the file back the remove linux machine.

What I'm missing with notepad++ is intellisense, autocode complete, and couple of features that will help me code faster.

I've used Eclipse before where I could code locally, and integrate with version control. However in this case, the files are located remotely and I cannot integrate with version control.

Any one else in a similar situation that has a working solution they can explain?

Comment: Ask your sysAdmin to install a SVN server on remote machine. this does not feel right.

Comment: We already have a custom version control.

Answer (score 4):

This is the goal of Eclipse's Target Management (TM) and Remote Systems Explorer (RSE) projects:  http://www.eclipse.org/tm/ .  Also see their FAQ:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/TM_and_RSE_FAQ

Comment: That said, +1 for Will's suggestion of SSHFS.

Comment: Can TM/RSE be installed on eclipse Indigo? In eclipse, at what site location can I find TM/RSE? (I'm a newbie)

Comment: Yes, TM/RSE is fully supported under Indigo.  As for download/installation, please follow the links in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html), then you can remotely mount the remote files and treat them as if they were local. If you have a huge project, maybe it's not efficient enough, or if you have a crummy connection. But it's a nice way to bring remote resources local to your machine.

Addenda:

I don't know much about Windows, but I found this [link](http://dokan-dev.net/en/download/).

Regarding rsync, rsync is a manual after the fact process. With SSHFS you can save or build files, "alt - tab" over to the terminal window and the files are already on the server. We've used it for PHP development. Edit files locally, save the files, tab to the browser on the server and hit refresh -- shazam.

Comment: SSHFS seems interesting, but looks like its only for unix type systems (correct me), my local development box is windows and remote development box is linux.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, from the mention of putty I infer you're running Windows.

Choice number one: get an operating system.

Sorry, I just had to say it.

Okay, you've really got two choices.

Choice one: use some kind of distributed configuration management system.  Among the possibilities are darcs, bazaar, git, and mercurial.  Subversion can access files remotely, so it can do the same thing in limited senses.  In all of these cases, you can basically replicate your files to the local machine and return them using simple commands that more or less optimally transfer the files.

Choice two: use a remote file system.  SSHFS, and FTP file systems are good.  I'd recommend [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/), which I've used very happily for some years on Macs.  It's now available for windows too.

Perhaps the easiest version of this is [DropBox](http://db.tt/xg8SO2z), which replicates files across all your machines, including Linux.  It's not very real-time, but it doesn't sound like you need that.  I use DropBox between home, laptop, and work (on a linux machine) and by the time I've gotten to the office, all my changes at home are replicated.